# Partial derivative tangent line?

Tags: calculus

Find the tangent line to curve $y^2-2x-4xy-1=0$ at the point $(-2,1)$ (Do not use $dy/dx=-Fx/Fy$)

I can solve this with $-Fx/Fy$ but i cant because question want a different method

thanks.

Comment: I would be inclined to say that 2yy'- 2- 4xy'- 4y=0 so that at (-2, 1) 2y'- 2+ 8y'- 4= 0 and then 10y'= 6 so y'= 6/10= 3/5.  Of course, when we divide both sides by 10 we are really dividing -Fx by Fy but at least it is not obvious!

Comment: why -1 will be -4y?

Comment: The point $(-2,1)$ is not on the curve. Have you mistyped the equation?

Comment: what does it mean "The point (−2,1) is not on the curve." is the answer? no ı am sure its true

Comment: If $F(x,y)=y^2-2x-4xy-1$, then $F(-2,1)=12\neq 0$

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate each term with respect to x, assuming that $y$ is a function of $x$.

From $$y^2-2x-4xy-1=0$$  we get $$2y y'-2 - (4y+4xy')=0$$

Plug in the information $x=-2$ and $y=1$ and solve for $y'$

$2y'-2-(4-8y')=0$ to get $10y' =6$ which gives $y'=3/5$

Comment: why -1 will be -4y?

Comment: -1 drops out. The -4y is part to the derivative of $-4xy$ using product rule.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is easy to just solve for $x$ to get

$$x=\frac{y^2-1}{4y+1}$$

for $y\neq -1/2$.

Differentiating we get

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1+y+y^2}{(1+2y)^2}$$

from which you can find the slope at any point on the curve (to get $dy/dx$ at any point just take the reciprocal of $dx/dy$ at that point).